# Insert textbox in RadzenDataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, radzen

I have a RadzenDataGrid that has a series of columns with data, one of this is a string that I want to represent as a textbox so the user can input data and then when clicking a "submit"  execute the stored procedure that updated these fields, I don't understand how to do the 2 way binding as it's giving me error when I try to ad the "@bind-Value=@Comments" property.

my datagrid has the following:

```
<RadzenDataGrid AllowSorting="true" AllowColumnReorder="true"  AllowMultiColumnSorting="true"  PageSize="40" AllowFiltering="true" FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" Data="@FilteredExpendituresList" TItem="Expenditure" AllowPaging="true" PagerHorizontalAlign="HorizontalAlign.Left" ShowPagingSummary="true">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Expenditure" Property="EmployeeName" Title="Employee Name" Visible=@FilteredExpendituresList.Any(x=>x.EmployeeName is not null) />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Expenditure" Property="EmployeeNumber" Title="Employee Number" Sortable="false" Width="125px" Visible=@FilteredExpendituresList.Any(x=>x.EmployeeNumber is not null)  TextAlign="TextAlign.Center"/>
        <RadzenTextBox  @bind-Value=@Comment  Class="w-100" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
```

and my object filling receives:

```
[Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<Expenditure> FilteredExpendituresList { get; set; } = null!;
```

with the class being:

```
public class Expenditure
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

How should I do so the datagrid can have the 2 way binding and have the Comment field that is input being passed from the textbox to the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Template`:

```
<RadzenDataGrid AllowSorting="true" AllowColumnReorder="true" AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" PageSize="40" AllowFiltering="true" FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" Data="@FilteredExpendituresList" TItem="Expenditure" AllowPaging="true" PagerHorizontalAlign="HorizontalAlign.Left" ShowPagingSummary="true">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Expenditure" Property="EmployeeName" Title="Employee Name" Visible=@FilteredExpendituresList.Any(x => x.EmployeeName is not null) />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Expenditure" Property="EmployeeNumber" Title="Employee Number" Sortable="false" Width="125px" Visible=@FilteredExpendituresList.Any(x => x.EmployeeNumber is not null) TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" />

        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Expenditure">
            <Template Context="data">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="@data.Comment" Class="w-100" />
            </Template>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>

    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
```

[Documentation](https://blazor.radzen.com/docs/guides/components/datagrid.html#columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Template` `RenderFragment<T>` inside a `RadzenDataGridColumn` if you have a global save.

If you want to use the `EditTemplate` `RenderFragment<T>`, you need to tell the Data Grid component that you want to edit by using a `RadzenDataGrid<T>` referenced object and call `EditRow(T item)`. It will then go into an edit state.

Within a `RadzenDataGridColumn` you need to then add an `EditTemplate` tag for the `RenderFragment<T>`.

Refer to their documentation for detailed examples: https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid-inline-edit